# Send string array in c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, cstring

my c# part

```
[DllImport("asdf.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    unsafe extern public static int CompareDB(string[] filename);
```

Below is c++ part

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)int CompareDB(char** name)
{             
    CString filename="It is already assigned in previous code"    
    strcpy(name[1], (const char *)fileName); 
}
```

Error is related with attempting to read or write protected memory.

Somebody help me please.

Comment: How do you know that `name[1]` will be large enough to contain the string?  Do you have some convention that all strings are allocated to be a certain size?

Comment: Can you change the calling sequence of `CompareDB`?  If so, the solution suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450074/passing-an-array-of-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll-function-and-fill-it-in-the) might apply.